# Library and setup to image optimization in backend for a mobile full screen

Tags: android, ios, image, performance

I'm developing a backend for a mobile app, the app is quite simple: it shows full screen images that users upload to the php backend.

I would like to process the images to optimize the quality, photo headers and size in order to save server and client data and time loading.

After some time searching I found libraries like ImageMagick or Vips, but it seems not designed for this purpose.

Do you know any straight forward library and recommended setup to this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I think ImageMagick does what you need.

```
convert image.png -resize 320x480 image_iphone3dot5inches.png
convert image.png -resize 640x960 image_iphone3dot5inches@2x.png
...
```

You can even specify the kind of algorithm you'd like to use for better results. cf. [this page for more information](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/)

Comment: Thank you! What about png or jpg compression? Or jpg and png removed headers? It's surprising for me there isn't more examples in this area.